# Directories and file kind pattern in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code search specification I would like to combine directories and file kind specifications.

For example, I would like to search for particular string in all `foo*.txt` files under directory `bar/var/extern`. Another example: I would like to exclude from search directories `out`, `tmp` **and** files `*.o`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example1:

- Files to include: `bar/var/extern/**/foo*.txt`

This will include every single `foo*.txt` under `bar/var/extern/` and it's subdirectories.

Example2:

- Files to exclude: `out, tmp, *.o`

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options